# how to delete an element in a column based on value of another column in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm working on a dataset where there are two columns, A and B.

If A has a NA value in a specific row, I want to change B into an NA value at that specific row as well and then continue for the rest of the column.

Anyone have any tips on a good way to do this?

Comment: Try `df[is.na(df$A), "B"] <- NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dummy <- data.frame(A = sample(c(1, 2, 3, NA), size = 20, replace = T),
                    B = sample(1:4, size = 20, replace = T))

dummy$B[is.na(dummy$A)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster approach with `data.table`.  It assigns (`:=`) the NAs in place for corresponding NA values in 'a'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[is.na(a), b := NA]
```

#### data

```
temp <- data.frame(a=c(NA, 1:5, NA, 3,4), b=6:14)
```